# Create a New array from foreach in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I'm a total CodeIgniter noob. I'm trying to update a few items in the DB coming from a foreach loop.

```
foreach($transfer_lists as $lists) {
   $this->db->from('tasks');
   $this->db->where('task_list_id', $lists['list_id']);
   $transfer_lists_check=$this->db->get()->result_array();      

   $transfer_new = array_shift($transfer_lists_check);

   $new_array = array(
      'task_id'           => $transfer_new['task_id'],
      'task_project_id'   => $new_project_id
   );
}

$this->db->update_batch('tasks', $new_array, 'task_list_id');
```

My newly created array is returning one array item, only. It should return 3, as that's how many there are in the DB with that specific list_id.

As you can see from the code, I'm trying to batch_update specific Tasks with a pre-set $project_id, hence why I need the array.

I'm banging my head against the wall trying to find a solution, but couldn't yet find something similar in Stack, or simply I don't know how to search :/

**UPDATE**

After conversing with @akshay-hedge below, I came to realization that I was trying to get 3 results in a 'foreach' loop with 1 reference.

**Solution**: Including another 'foreach' within a 'foreach' to build my array as needed.

Updated code below:

```
foreach($transfer_lists as $lists) {
   $this->db->from('tasks');
   $this->db->where('task_list_id', $lists['list_id']);
   $tasks_found=$this->db->get()->result_array();       

        // Solution to get the desired Array I was looking for
        foreach($tasks_found as $tasks) {
            $new_array[] = array(
                'task_id'           => $tasks['task_id'],
                'task_project_id'   => $new_project_id
            );
        }

}

$this->db->update_batch('tasks', $new_array, 'task_list_id');
```

**UPDATE 2**

After, some more conversing, @akshay-hedge suggested another solution without using any 'foreach', by building an array starting from 'task_list_id', which I have initially.

Please, check the accepted Answer below for the solution.

Comment: $new_array[] add this to your code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to append data in existing array without overwrite whole array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12893246/how-to-append-data-in-existing-array-without-overwrite-whole-array)

Comment: @bishop It's odd that I'm getting 1 result on the array even after [] (please check my comments below on the answer by Akshay // Although print_r($transfer_lists_check) returns an array with all three results // But, what I need is a NEW array for each task_id found (3 in total with x value for list_id) — if all this makes any sense :/

Comment: @bishop I've updated my Question with new info/solution / hope doing it like this is OK as well (?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got something small to fix:

`$new_array = array( .. )` - with this you are overwriting array in each iteration

`$new_array[] = array( .. )` - with this you are adding new element to array (`$new_array`) in each iteration.

So modify your code

**From**

```
 $new_array = array(
      'task_id'           => $transfer_new['task_id'],
      'task_project_id'   => $new_project_id
   );
```

**TO**

```
 $new_array[] = array(
      'task_id'           => $transfer_new['task_id'],
      'task_project_id'   => $new_project_id
   );
```

Since you got list of `list_ids` you can use `where_in`

```
$new_array = $this->db->select("'$new_project_id' as task_project_id,task_id",FALSE)
->where_in('task_list_id', array_column($transfer_lists,'list_id'))
->from('tasks')
->get()
->result_array();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @akshay-hedge, but that solution is returning me only one item on the array (the first task from the loop)...

Comment: I noticed [] @akshay-hedge, though still 1 result / if I print_r($transfer_lists_check) I get all 3 results, however doing a print_r($new_array) after the fact, I'm getting 1 result only. Not sure where I'm going wrong : /

Comment: @OctoberEleven: do you mean to say, for one task_list_id, 3 results ??? why there is array_shift ???

Comment: @akshay-hedge I used array_shift so I can access $transfer_new['task_id'] (one level up on the array) / and Yes, there are 3 items on the table 'tasks' with the 'task_list_id' of x

Comment: if 3 items are then with this `$new_array[]` it should work, make sure you defined `$new_array = array();` before loop starts

Comment: @akshay-hedge you're question above about trying to get 3 results from 1 task_list_id, got me thinking that my 'foreach' wasn't setup right. Please check my Update on my Question. Can it be done like that? (Also, I'm trying your solution with 'where_in' as well)

Comment: @OctoberEleven did you try, another approach with where_in clause, this one is without using foreach

Comment: @akshay-hedge Perfect! That works without any 'foreach' / I would guess this is better, performance wise? (BTW, if you can edit "$this>" into "$this->" for anyone else who might not see it)

Comment: @OctoberEleven: sorry, fixed typo, thanks for informing